# VBA IE Automation - Read iFrame

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, iframe, automation

Our business uses a browser-based program for operations. I'm automating a solution to navigate through this site, and retrieve some data at the end.

The site itself uses regular frames very heavily. However, at the very end of my process, it populates my data not into a frame, but an iFrame. There's also very extensive javascript throughout the site, making things muddy.

Grabbing the iFrame's src URL and opening in a new browser errors out the page (i.e. the page displays error text instead of the content).

**My question:**

How can I grab the text out of an iFrame through VBA?

**What I've tried so far** *(feel free to skip)*:

*Target a specific iFrame in a specific frame, and grab innerHTML*

```
With ie.document.frames(myFrameNum).document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(1).document.body
stringResult = .innerHTML
```

*Target a specific iFrame by ID in a specific frame, and grab innerHTML*

```
Dim iFrm As HTMLIFrame
Set iFrm = ie.document.frames(myFrameNum).document.getElementByID("iFrameID")
Debug.Print iFrm.document.body.innerText
```

*Find any instances of iFrames, and grab them* (No results - perhaps because the iframe is embeded in a frame?)

```
Dim iFrm As HTMLIFrame
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
 For iterator = 0 To ie.document.all.Length - 1
  If TypeName(ie.document.all(iterator)) = "HTMLIFrame" Then
   Set iFrm = ie.document.all(iterator)
   Set doc = iFrm.document
   Debug.Print & doc.body.outerHTML
  End If
Next
```

Comment: If you share the link i can try. This link may be helpful for you http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40649

Comment: What were the specific issues with what you've already tried? The code for *"Target a specific iFrame in a specific frame, and grab innerHTML"* looks like it would be correct.

Comment: @Santosh It's a private intranet site, so I can't share. However, I did see that post previously. The issue is that when I try to navigate to the iframe src as it suggests, the page errors. I don't believe navigating to the page is an option.

Comment: @Gaffi The issue with that option is that it's pulling the wrong HTML. I'm not getting the content of the iFrame, but rather the html that includes the iframe tag itself.

Comment: @AaronContreras i have done this. Again it was intranet site.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue and I got the solution using the following line of script..

IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).**contentDocument**.getElementsbyTagName("body")(0).innertext

Comment: This question is a bit old, so I no longer have the project up in front of me. However, I'll see about digging it up soon and testing this out, for posterity. I will say that this at least looks promising, I googled around different parts of it and there seems to be some consensus about its (or very similar code's) use.

Comment: I know the question is a bit old..and I landed on this page searching solutions...but somehow I got the solution so I pasted what helped me ...may be some one in future gets the benefit..didn't understood the reason of voting it down?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it was downvoted either, but it wasn't by me. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry .. no problem..Whoever has down voted it must have a better solution..Please paste the solution anonymous person..please share your knowledge..

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

```
Dim elemCollection As IHTMLElementCollection

Set elemCollection = objDoc.frames("iFrameID").document.all
Debug.Print elemCollection.Item("pagemenuli-adv").innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, finally solved it using:

ObjIE.document.frames(0).document.forms(0).innerText

Note: The text which I was in need was present in form which is located in a iframe.

Am new to VBA, can some body explain what exactly 0 in Frames(0)/forms (0) is?

If it something like Frame index or frame number(As of my assumption) please let me know how can we find frame index(in any HTML)?

Comment: You shouldn't ask questions in your answers

Comment: Didn't check tips, sorry for that, I will post a new Question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
`Dim iFrm As HTMLIFrame
Set iFrm = ie.document.frames(myFrameNum).document.getElementByID("iFrameID")
Debug.Print iFrm.contentDocument.body.innerHTML`
```

Comment: Did you just copy/paste this from the "Things I've tried that didn't work" section??