# Selecting/actioning items in Kendo UI widgets using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

Stuck - Need help !

I'm trying to automate actioning items in an IE web page on our internal company site. I'm able to fill out any kind of **text object**, click on a **submit button** etc., but several items are either in a **grid/table (Kendo Grid)** or a **dropdown** list. I just can't seem to figure out how to select from these grids/tables or dropdowns.

I've tried everything I can think of, to no avail. I've used `getElementById()`, `getElementsByTagName()`, `getElementsByName()`, and even some web scraping techniques.

Unfortunately, as the web page is on an internal site, no one else will be able to test against it.

This is the main part of my code

```
 'After opening the web page, inserting a number, selecting the "search"
 ' (all from the VBA script), I have to use a "mousemove", "mousedown" and     
 ' "mouseup" to select the item, whick is what the "myClick" subroutine does

     myClick '<<< THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GET RID OF >>>

   'I left the following segment in to show that I'm able to do several other functions        
    myDocs = ie.Document.getElementById("DispatchComments").Value

    If myInfo = True Then
        ie.Document.getElementById("DispatchComments").Value = "__" & myCell5 & "__" & myDocs
    Else: End If

   'IF ESTIMATED TIME IS LESS THAN 0, ENTER 120 - Enter estimated time    
  If ie.Document.getElementById("TotalEstimatedTime").Value < 10 Then
    ie.Document.getElementById("TotalEstimatedTime").Value = 120

   Else: End If

  End With

End Sub
```

`

This is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi7w7.jpg) after entering the lease number and clicking the search button. The only way I've managed to select the row is to programmatically click the mouse in one of the three white-background areas shown. My code uses `mousemove` and coordinates to select the row, scroll down to a tank dropdown and click it open so I can manually choose a tank number.

This portion of the code is where I'm stuck

```
Set myChoice1 = ie.Document.getElementById("drgdLease").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1)
        With myChoice1
         .getElementsByTagName("td")(0).Focus '<<---Works all the way to here
         .FireEvent ("onmouseover")           '<<---No errors from this point on
         .FireEvent ("onmousedown")                'but doesn't do anything
         .FireEvent ("onmouseup")
         .FireEvent ("onclick")                '<<---some other things tried
         .FireEvent ("ondblclick")
         .FireEvent ("onselect")
         td.innerText = value
         td.innerHTML = value
        End With

'<tr role="row" data-uid="db62d811-4337-477c-a0fd-0e9e036670bb">
'  <td role="gridcell">998262</td> '<<---This is the info/row I need to select
'  <td role="gridcell">HENDERSON (SMACKOVER) STORAGE</td>
'  <td role="gridcell">ORYAN OIL &amp; GAS</td>
```

Inspecting the element for the area I'm trying to select shows this HTML

```js
 name="Result">
 <div class="k-widget k-grid" id="drgdLease" style="-ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom pinch-zoom;" data-role="grid">
    <table class="k-selectable" role="grid" style="-ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom pinch-zoom;" data-role="selectable">
       <colgroup>
          <col>
          <col>
          <col>
       </colgroup>
       <thead class="k-grid-header" role="rowgroup">
          <tr role="row">
             <th class="k-header k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Lease Number" data-index="0" data-field="LeaseCode" data-role="columnsorter">
                <a tabindex="-1" class="k-header-column-menu" href="#">
                   <span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-s"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="k-link" href="/LeaseProfiles/GetLeasesSearch?Length=9&amp;drgdLease-sort=LeaseCode-asc">Lease Number</a>
             </th>
             <th class="k-header k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Lease Name" data-index="1" data-field="LeaseName" data-role="columnsorter">
                <a tabindex="-1" class="k-header-column-menu" href="#">
                   <span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-s"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="k-link" href="/LeaseProfiles/GetLeasesSearch?Length=9&amp;drgdLease-sort=LeaseName-asc">Lease Name</a>
              </th>
             <th class="k-header k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Lease Operator" data-index="2" data-field="LeaseOperator.OperatorName" data-role="columnsorter">
                <a tabindex="-1" class="k-header-column-menu" href="#">
                   <span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-s"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="k-link" href="/LeaseProfiles/GetLeasesSearch?Length=9&amp;drgdLease-sort=LeaseOperator.OperatorName-asc">Lease Operator</a>
             </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>

<!--
 This is what the code looks like before selecting the item. 
 ie: before clicking  anywhere on the row.
-->

       <tbody role="rowgroup">
          <tr role="row" data-uid="db62d811-4337-477c-a0fd-0e9e036670bb">
             <td role="gridcell">998262</td>                         
             <td role="gridcell">HENDERSON (SMACKOVER) STORAGE</td>
             <td role="gridcell">ORYAN OIL &amp; GAS</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>

<!--
 This is what the code changes to after clicking the row. 
 Note the class and arial are added on the `tr role` line, which may be binding  the data.
-->

 <tr role="row" data-uid="db62d811-4337-477c-a0fd-0e9e036670bb" class = "k-state- selected" arial = "true">
   <td role="gridcell">998262</td> 
   <td role="gridcell">HENDERSON (SMACKOVER) STORAGE</td>
   <td role="gridcell">ORYAN OIL &amp; GAS</td>
```

Comment: If you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` do you get errors, and on which lines ?

Comment: I just tried it on the code "as is", and didn't get any errors.

Comment: The previous code snippet was a jumbled up mess. I've redone it to make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: Perhaps someone could give me a javascript solution, or at least _something_ to try. I've tried everything I can think of or found on this site and others. **Mitch**

Comment: is this page similar to what you are trying to automate ?
  ..... http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

Comment: @jsotola It looks almost identical in the structure. I'll check it out today and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Mitch, either the element is not receiving the event (assigned on <td>) or a floating element is supposed to catch it. Try the first `<td>` or to the element at location (`var box=target.getBoundingClientRect(), document.elementFromPoint(box.left+box.width/2, box.top+box.height/2).click()`). In could also be that the listener is expected an event with specific arguments. In any case you should hit F12, select the DOM element, and check the registered events in the panel on the right. Then add a breakpoint on the listener and emit some events in the console to figure-out the reason.

Comment: @FlorentB. Unfortunately I'm a moron, and don't quite understand how to use the statement you posted. I'm not sure if it goes in as vba or javascript. VB is telling me "Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement". Thank you for taking the time to look at this. Perhaps you could nudge me in right direction with a couple of sample lines ? I started off with this line `Set elm = doc.getElementById("drgdLease").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1)` which is the 2nd tr under the id, then there are 3 td's below that. I may be going way too far down in the code to achieve what I need.

Comment: @Mitch, the statement goes in the console from IE. You need to replace `target` by the targeted element. It should be `document.querySelector("#drgdLease tbody tr:nth-child(1) td")` in your case. Bottom line is you need to analyse the event handler in the page to understand why the click is not handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to select the first row of the kendoGrid:

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#drgdLease').data('kendoGrid').select('tr:eq(0)');"
```

Below is a demo showing the equivalent code working on the official [Kendo UI Grid Widget Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) page.

**Note the work-around for the possible race condition.** While it may be that this particular race condition also applies in your case, there is *another* race condition that you need to be aware of.

It's possible that, after having initiated the search for the lease number, and *before* the kendoGrid has finished updating, your code might attempt to select the first row. This would result in the first row of the default displayed data/previous search data being selected, and *then* the grid being updated, causing the selection to disappear.

The work-around employed in the code below ***will not work*** in this case, as it will always (incorrectly) detect a selected row. A different workaround is needed. (I can think of a few - the most suitable probably depending on your exact use case.)

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <in any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : Microsoft Internet Controls   [SHDocVw]
' Source     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483783/1961728
'============================================================================================
  ' Required if late binding SHDocVw
  Private Enum tagREADYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING
    READYSTATE_LOADED
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  End Enum

Public Sub AutomateKendoUI()

  ' Create and use a new instance of IE
  With New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer '##Late Binding: CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = True ' False is default

    .Navigate "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index"
    Do Until .Busy = False And .ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop '##Late Binding: = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE  ##No Enums: = 4

    ' Get and use the main DOM
    With .Document
      ' Race Condition Work-Around
      '   Kendo UI may not have finished loading the Grid data before we invoke its select method.
      '   Therefore, we continue to invoke the method until a selected row is detected.
      Do
        .parentWindow.execScript "$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').select('tr:eq(0)');"
        On Error Resume Next
          Dim elm_tr As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow: Set elm_tr = .querySelector("#grid tr.k-state-selected")
        On Error GoTo 0
      Loop While elm_tr Is Nothing

    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

---

### **Sources:**

From the [official Kendo UI API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select) for the `select` method<sup>[1](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select)</sup>:

> Example - select the first and second table rows
>   
> ...
>
> ```
> var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
> grid.select("tr:eq(1), tr:eq(2)");
> ```

Note that this is actually ***wrong***. The first row is at index 0, *not* index 1. A string parameter for the select method is treated as a jQuery selector, and from the [official jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for the `:eq()` selector<sup>[2](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)</sup>:

> **eq selector**
>
> **Description:** *Select the element at index *`n`* within the matched set.*
>
> `jQuery(":eq(index)")`
>
> **index:** ***Zero***-based index of the element to match.

Interestingly, the [official Kendo UI API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-tbody) for the `tbody` object gets it right though<sup>[3](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-tbody)</sup>:

> Example - get the first table row
>   
> ...
>
> ```
> var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
> var row = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(0)");
> ```

---

<sup><sub>1 http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select

  2 https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

  3 http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-tbody</sub></sup>

Comment: OMG, Robin, the single line worked with only one exception, which was easy to figure out. The index number on this part `select('tr:eq(6)` selected the row perfectly. A thousand thanks for the solution, the exceptional documentation, and taking the time to show an old man something new. Regards

Comment: @Mitch That's great! Do you still need to know how to select from a Kendo dropdown list? If so, ask another question, pop a comment here and I'll help you out. And don't forget to include all the relevant HTML.

Comment: Yes, I still need to know how to do a dropdown. At this point what I'm doing is just "opening" the dropdown and choosing an option manually. I need to work on it myself before asking another question, to see if I can figure it out first. This is the code I'm using now `Set objButton = ie.Document.getElementById("Tank_ID")
            objButton.Focus
            objButton.Click`

Comment: I've posted a new question with code, jquery script and a few things I've tried to select an item in a dropdown listbox. I guess I'm gonna need some help with this one too, if you don't mind. You can find it here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497282/im-trying-to-select-and-item-from-a-dropdown-kendolistbox-in-ie-with-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

here is a shot in the dark .... lol

this may be a similar page

single step the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub extractKendo()

'    Dim IE As Object
'    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index"

    While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.Document

    Dim elm As IHTMLElementCollection

    Set elm = doc.getElementsByClassName("k-link k-pager-nav")
    elm(0).Click
    elm(4).Click
    elm(0).Click
    elm(3).Click
    elm(3).Click
    elm(3).Click
    elm(0).Click

    Set elm = doc.getElementsByClassName("k-list-scroller")
    Set elm = elm(1).getElementsByTagName("li")

    elm(0).Click
    elm(1).Click
    elm(2).Click
    elm(3).Click

    ie.Quit

    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @jsotola . Although none of it has worked so far, `k-link` had 74 elements, which "clicked" everything _but_ that row. However I'm still trying different class names, tag names, index numbers. I'm not giving up. Mitch

Comment: I just used your method above for a completely different problem I've been dealing with (and pulling my hair out over). Just wanted to take a moment and say Thank You ! I knew this would come in handy one day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. I tried to explain as much as possible in the comments. Let me know how it's going, based on the HTML posted, it seems like this should work, but please let us know :)

I'm assuming you already have an IE window open and need to get a pointer to that window. Update the "**myWebSiteURL**" in the **getIEPointer** function to be the URL of the site you are trying to access. Less is more in this case as I'm doing a wildcard match. E.g. looking for 'goo' would match a url of 'Good' and 'Google'.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getElements()
    Dim ie As Object

    'I'm assuming you already have it open in IE, if not, then load the page
    Set ie = getIEPointer("myWebSiteURL")

    'Exit if the window couldn't be located
    If ie Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No Window Found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim element As Object

    'get the Div element which contains all the elements we are interested in
    'If this doesn't work, make sure your pages doesn't contain FRAMES
    'Here's a page about Frames
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699267/vba-ie-automation-read-iframe
    Set element = ie.Document.getElementById("drgdLease")

    'Select the first instance of the tbody element in the drgdLease div
    Set element = element.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)

    'Select the first instance of the td, inside the TBody
    Set element = element.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)

    'Interact with the element
    element.Click
    element.Value = "12345"

End Sub

'This function will return an IE object, I'm assuming the page is already open
Private Function getIEPointer(ByRef UrlPart As String) As Object
    Dim window As Object

    For Each window In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows()
        If window.LocationURL Like "*" & UrlPart & "*" Then
            Set getIEPointer = window
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    Set getIEPointer = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan for taking the time to look at this. I'm not sure about the frames thing. Everything is dynamic based upon certain choices made along the way. I don't have a problems **opening the page**, getting a number into the **lease name** text entry, and clicking on the **search button**. It's at that point the row/s of item/s comes up. That's where I'm stuck. I will be back to work on Thursday and give your script a try (as I can't try it from home). Again, thanks

Comment: Ok Mitch, thanks. Maybe it's just me but your problem is a little unclear still. Are you trying to find/pick a specific row from a table? If true, are there any identifiable features from one row to the next that would narrow the search?

Comment: Ryan, If you click on the screen shot above, it will show the screen as it looks at the point I'm stuck. I would think a simple click would do, but every scenario I've tried does nothing. I know that after clicking the line (row) with a mouse, one of the code lines changes to something like `class = "k-State-Selected", aria - Selected = "true"`, which I think is part of this line `<tr role="row" data-uid="db62d811-4337-477c-a0fd-0e9e036670bb">` but I'm not sure.

Comment: I asked the guy that authored the page how to do it, and he sent me this: `.Document.getElementById("drgdLease").Data("kendogrid").Select ("tr:eq(1)")`, but this gives me an error of "this method not supported". Then I got chastised for writing something that was unauthorized, so that was the end of any help from him.

Comment: So you are trying to click a row, click a column header, something else? I'm still a little unclear what the outcome should be. Do you have to click one of those cells for the data to become available somehow?

Comment: Trying to click on the row, not a column header. I've edited the code above to reflect the before and after selection change that occurs.

Comment: No luck with your code above. It runs all the way through with no errors, but doesn't "click" anything. I tried `elm.select` (not supported), `elm.selected = true` (not supported). Ugh , you wouldn't think it would be that hard, but with these Kendo widgets and javascript, every "normal" method just doesn't work.

Comment: If the page has jQuery you can try something like: `ie.document.Parent.ExecScript "$(""table:eq(0) tr:first"").click();"` This will click the first row in the first table. Have you reviewed which events are related to that element (you can see this in the event section in IE). You may need to fire the `Change()` event. So something like: `ie.document.Parent.ExecScript "$(""table:eq(0) tr:first"").click().Change();"` might be needed, although I'm not sure.

Comment: Ryan, Inspecting the element and looking at the events tab, the only line I can see that has an event is `<table class="k-selectable" role="grid" style="-ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom pinch-zoom;" data-role="selectable">` , which has **click**, **mousedown** and **pointerdown**, each of which has `jquery.min.js(3)` out to the right of each one.

Comment: Well good news is the page has jQuery, let me know the result of the other script.

Comment: Using this `ie.document.Parent.ExecScript "$(""table:eq(0) tr:first"").click();"` I got **Object doesn't support this property or method**. Same result with "Change" added. Using ParentNode instead of Parent, it wants an Object.