# I'm trying to select and item from a dropdown kendolistbox in IE with Excel Vba

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, vba

I found a solution to choosing a fixed selection from a dropdown list. **Now all I have to do is figure out how to choose an item based on the choices**.

The following chooses the **first** item in the dropdown, however, I found out that making the dropdown "open" is *not* necessary.

Changing the **select** parameter to 2 chooses the second item in the list etc.

I suppose trying to use `getElementById` and cycling through the innerText may be the way to go, since I don't know any other way.

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#drgdTankCrude').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($('#Tank_ID').data('kendoDropDownList').select(1));"
```

Here a section of the web page code.

```
 <input name="Tank.ID" id="Tank_ID" style="width: 200px; display: none;" type="text" data-role="dropdownlist"></span>

'Lots of other stuff in here for formatting

<div class="k-widget k-grid" id="drgdTankCrude" style="left: 890.32px; top: 93.7px; display: block; position: absolute;" data-role="grid">

<table class="k-selectable" role="grid" style="-ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom pinch-zoom;" data-role="selectable">

  <colgroup><col><col></colgroup>

  <thead class="k-grid-header" role="rowgroup">

    <tr role="row">
      <th class="k-header" scope="col" data-title="Tank" data-index="0" data-field="ID"><span class="k-link">Tank</span></th>
      <th class="k-header" scope="col" data-title="Capacity" data-index="1" data-field="Capacity"><span class="k-link">Capacity</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">
       <tr class="k-state-selected" aria-selected="true">
        <td>179800</td>
        <td>202.06</td></tr>
       <tr class="k-alt" aria-selected="false">
        <td>179801</td>
        <td>202.82</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

'Code before dropdown

<tbody role="rowgroup">
     <tr>
        <td>179800</td>
        <td>202.06</td></tr>
     <tr class="k-alt">
        <td>179801</td>
        <td>202.82</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>

'Code before dropdown opens

<div class="k-widget k-grid" id="drgdTankCrude" style="left: 890.32px; top: 93.71px; display: none; position: absolute;" data-role="grid">

'Code change after dropdown opens

<div class="k-widget k-grid **k-custom-visible**" id="drgdTankCrude" style="left: 890.32px; top: 93.71px; display: block; position: absolute;" data-role="grid">

'Code change after making a selection

<tbody role="rowgroup">
   <tr class="k-state-selected" aria-selected="true">
    <td>179800</td>              '<<-----This item selected
    <td>202.06</td></tr>
   <tr class="k-alt" aria-selected="false"> '<<--If selected then unselected
    <td>179801</td>                             'otherwise ends at k-alt">
    <td>202.82</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I'm having understanding exactly what happens when the dropdown list is opened. Can you post a screenshot of the opened list and whatever HTML changes when you open it (both before and after)?

Comment: @robinCTS There aren't any code changes when the dropdown opens, only up selection. Sorry about the first screenshot, I screwed it up. Some dropdowns only have one item, others may have up to 20. If this can't be figured out, don't sweat it, your first solution put me light years ahead of where I was. Again, thank you for taking the time. Perhaps this will help someone else with similar issues.

Comment: @robinCTS I was wrong about code changes on opening the dropdown, I've edited and added the before and after. Not much change though. Just this in the line `k-custom-visible`

Comment: Aha! A kendo grid ***inside*** a kendo dropdown list! If I'd been more familiar with Kendo UI, I would have realized sooner. Should be able to figure it out now.

Comment: I've made one single step of progress using a different statement to open the kendoDropDownList. Edited in the first screen above.

Comment: @robinCTS Well, I'm stuck again. I've tried everything I can think of in various combinations to no avail. I've edited the code above to show the jQuery code and one particular line of my code that doesn't error, but doesn't select the item either. I've also tried closing the listbox, but that errored also. Mind taking a look for me ?  BTW: The listbox now opens with `ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#Tank_ID').kendoDropDownList('open');"`

Comment: @robinCTS I finally found the line that puts the tank number in !! Now I just have to figure out how to go about choosing from a multiple list. I'm so proud of myself. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to selecting the first item in a kendoDropDownList ..

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#drgdTankCrude').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($('#Tank_ID').data('kendoDropDownList').select(1));"
```