# VBA Excel data scrape, deep HTML

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to scrape from intranet site information marked red. Due to complexity of HTML I cannot do it on my own.

[image: link]

I was using that kind of code however it is not letting me go deeper than "windowshade-body" part.

```
Set myData = IE.Document.getElementById("windowshade").getElementsByClassName("windowshade-body").frames("windowShadeFrame").getElementsByClassName(" ie ie11     win32")(0)
Text = myData.innerHTML
Debug.Print Text
```

oes anyone have any idea how to take a bite from this? Would be thankful for any ideas. I have read many topic here, but I could not find a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699267/vba-ie-automation-read-iframe

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found a solution. That worked for me.

```
Set ifrm = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(5).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0)
Set text3 = ifrm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(ifrm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("tbody").Length - 1)
  Set text3 = text3.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("td")(1)

CountRows = CInt(Len(text3.outerHTML) - Len(Replace(text3.outerHTML, "iconSmallPaperclipVertical", ""))) / 26

MaxVal = Right(Split(text3.outerHTML, "id=" & Chr(34) & "0,")(0), 1)
For i = 1 To CountRows

If CDbl(MaxVal) < CDbl(Right(Split(text3.outerHTML, "id=" & Chr(34) & "0,")(0), 1)) Then
    rowID = Split(Split(text3.outerHTML, "o=" & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34) & ">")(0)
    MaxVal = Right(Split(text3.outerHTML, "id=" & Chr(34) & "0,")(0), 1)
End If
Next i
```