# How to input a number on an Internet Explorer element?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to input a number on an IE element (input) from Excel VBA.

I am not a HTML developer, but there are some frame codes that might influence my problem.

This is what I have in VBA:

```
IE.Navigate "http://thisandthat/herewego.asp"
           
IE.Document.getElementsbyId("txt_cod_re_rh").Value = "aaaa"
```

Nothing happens.

I also tried to get the element ID or test if VBA could see it, but it looks like VBA cannot find it on the page (tried ID and class):

```
Set element = Document.getElementByclass("select_st")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("b1").Value = element
```

This is my HTML:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBS">
smthing
</SCRIPT>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        
        
    <link href="../css/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="include/scripts.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function exibeRelatorierer(server) {

            d = window.document.frmFilter;

            var cod_VP = d.cbo_VP;
            var cod_periodo = d.cbo_Periodoerer;
            var cod_re_rh = d.txt_cod_re_rh;

            if (cod_re_rh.value == '') {
                cod_re_rh.value = "0";
            }

            if (cod_periodo.value == -1) {
                alert("Select smthing.");
            }else{
                if (d.TC[0].checked) {
                    parent.frames['frmMain'].location = servidor234234 + "RPT_CPR01884_TS" + "&rc:Area=Toolbar&rc:LinkTarget=frmMain&rc:JavaScript=True&rs:ClearSession=true&rc:Parameters=false" + "&COD_VP=" + cod_VP.value + "&COD_PERIODO=" + cod_periodo.value + "&COD_RE_RH=" + cod_re_rh.value
                } else {
                    parent.frames['frmMain'].location = servidor234234 + "RPT_CPR01884_CP" + "&rc:Area=Toolbar&rc:LinkTarget=frmMain&rc:JavaScript=True&rs:ClearSession=true&rc:Parameters=false" + "&COD_VP=" + cod_VP.value + "&COD_PERIODO=" + cod_periodo.value + "&COD_RE_RH=" + cod_re_rh.value
                }
```

I believe this code above is messing me up trying to insert value to the txt_cod_re_rh.
I read something about a frame? Is this element on another frame? (No idea, really.)

This is the code where the input box is:

```
<form id="Form1" name="frmFiltro">
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr class="table_bhoras1" height="50" align="center">
                     <td>Extração</td>
                 </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="Table3" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0" class="titsemlink2">
                    <TR class="titsemlink2">
                        <td>
                            Inform number: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="select_st" type="text" name="txt_cod_re_rh" id="txt_cod_re_rh" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </TR>
```

Comment: `IE.Document.getElementsbyId("txt_cod_re_rh").Value = "aaaa"` won't work. First, you need to get the frame where the input is. Read [VBA IE Automation - Read iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699267/vba-ie-automation-read-iframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typos in your code. The methods `.getElementsbyId` or `getElementByclass` do not exist within the `InternetExplorer` document object in VBA.

You can try this via element `id`:

```
Set element = IE.Document.getElementById("txt_cod_re_rh")
element.value = "aaaa"
```

Or via `classname`:

```
Set element = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("select_st")(0)
element.value = "aaaa"
```

Withou the full html is difficult to tell if it is inside an `iframe` or not.