# How do I get a table using getElementByID?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to take a table (HTML) using the method getElementByID but it doesn't work.

```
Sub GrabLastNames()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim data As Object, ele As Object
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = False

    objIE.navigate "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=93407&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    y = 1

     For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados")
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(3).textContent
        y = y + 1
    Next

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me why? I tryed diferents methods and it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to get the tabular content from that webpage. I used a different link within the script to be able to send xhr. You can find the link having static content using dev tools. I also used cookies in order for the script to work correctly. It is way faster then IE. Give it a shot:

```
Sub fetchTabularData()
    Const mainUrl = "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=93407&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2"
    Const Url$ = "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmDemonstracaoFinanceiraITR.aspx?"

    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object
    Dim S$, params$, R&, C&

    params = "Informacao=2&Demonstracao=4&Periodo=0&Grupo=DFs+Consolidadas&Quadro=Demonstra%c3%a7%c3%a3o+do+Resultado&NomeTipoDocumento=ITR&Empresa=MAGAZ%20LUIZA&DataReferencia=2020-03-31&Versao=1&CodTipoDocumento=3&NumeroSequencialDocumento=93407&NumeroSequencialRegistroCvm=2086&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2"

    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", mainUrl, False
        .send
        strCookie = .getAllResponseHeaders
        strCookie = Split(Split(strCookie, "Cookie:")(1), ";")(0)

        .Open "GET", Url & params, False
        .setRequestHeader "Cookie", Trim(strCookie)
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=93407&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each elem In .getElementById("ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados").Rows
            For Each tRow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = tRow.innerText
            Next tRow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to scroll down the page to take all data of a table? For example: I have this page "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MGLU3.SA/history?period1=1560211200&period2=1591142400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d" but when I use your method it didn't take all the table because the page didn't load completely.

Answer (score 1):

Because the id of the table you are looking for is inside an iFrame.

So you have to look inside the iFrames and not the main document.

This may help : [VBA IE Automation - Read iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699267/vba-ie-automation-read-iframe)

[image]

Comment: I used IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsbyTagName("table")(0).innertext but it gave me an unique text. Can I loop into it and transpose the table to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

In a well-writeed HTML, there is one and only one tag which id = `ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados`.
Which means your for-loop is not necessary.

You may try

```vb
Dim myTbs As Object, myTb As Object, i As Long

Set myTbs =  objIE.document.GetElementsByTagname("table")
For Each ele In myTbs
    If ele.Rows(0).Cells(0).InnerText = "firstHeader" Then
        Set myTb = ele
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To myTb.Rows.Count-1
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = myTb.Rows(i).Cells(0).textContent
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = myTb.Rows(i).Cells(1).textContent
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = myTb.Rows(i).Cells(2).textContent
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = myTb.Rows(i).Cells(3).textContent
Next i
```

Comment: I tryied this code and it didn't work. I guess it's because of the table is inside of an iFrame.